# how do I access data from JSON object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

inside my onMessage prop of react-native-webview am recieving the native event as follows

```
 {"nativeEvent": {"canGoBack": true, "canGoForward": false, "data": "{\"url\":\"some_url"}", "loading": false, "target": 313, "title": "Doctors Platform", "url": "some_url"}}
```

I want to access the url value inside data object, any idea how to do that?

My code :

```
 <WebView
    source={{
      uri: uri,
    }}
    renderLoading={renderLoadingView}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    startInLoadingState={true}
    // onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={onShouldStartLoadWithRequest} //ios
    onNavigationStateChange={onShouldStartLoadWithRequest} //android
    ref={webviewRef}
    injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
    onMessage={(event) => {
      let post = JSON.stringify(event.nativeEvent.data);
      console.log(event)
      console.log('post',post.message)
    }}
  />
```

Any suggestion would be great, do let me know id anything is required for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `JSON.parse` on the data property, then use `.url` it will return your desired result.

```js
const myevent =  {"nativeEvent": {"canGoBack": true, "canGoForward": false, "data": "{\"url\":\"some_url\"}", "loading": false, "target": 313, "title": "Doctors Platform", "url": "some_url"}};

console.log(JSON.parse(myevent.nativeEvent.data).url);
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of nativeEvent.data is a stringified object, you must parse it to retrieve the orginal object,you can use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/JSON/parse)

```js
const obj =  {"nativeEvent": {"canGoBack": true, "canGoForward": false, "data": "{\"url\":\"some_url\"}", "loading": false, "target": 313, "title": "Doctors Platform", "url": "some_url"}};
console.log(JSON.parse(obj.nativeEvent.data))
```